# Can't compile this F# code

Tags: f#

Can't compile this F# code because it was incorrectly translated from C#.

There appears to be a problem with a lambda expression

```
namespace OpenXML

open DocumentFormat.OpenXml
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing
// Add the DocumentFormat.OpenXml assembly
// Add the WindowsBase assembly

module public Word =

    let query_plain_text_content_control (document_path_and_file_name :string) (content_control_tag :string) =
        use theDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document_path_and_file_name, true)
        let mainPart = theDoc.MainDocumentPart
        let block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r :> r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val = content_control_tag).Single()
        let t = block.Descendants<Text>().FirstOrDefault()
        t.Text

    let update_plain_text_content_control (document_path_and_file_name :string) (content_control_tag :string) (new_text :string) = async {
        use theDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document_path_and_file_name, true)
        let mainPart = theDoc.MainDocumentPart
        let block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r :> r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val = content_control_tag).Single()
        let t = block.Descendants<Text>().FirstOrDefault()
        t.Text = new_text
        mainPart.Document.Save() |> ignore
        }
```

Comment: You should make sure to include the exact error message and which line it occurs on.

Comment: Welcome! Please include the exact errors you get.

Comment: Error 1 Unexpected symbol '(' in expression, Line 14,
Error 2 Unexpected symbol ')' in binding. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token. Line 14, 
Error 3 Unexpected symbol '(' in expression, Line 21, Error 4 Unexpected symbol ')' in binding. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token. Line 21

Comment: ':>' in F# is casting operator that converts a type to type that is higher in the hierarchy. It's not a lambda expression.

Comment: I think your latest edit has borderline turned this into a new question - the answer now makes no sense.  I think you would be better asking a new question.

Answer (score 2):

':>' in F# is casting operator that converts a type to type that is higher in the hierarchy. It's not a lambda expression. So probably this call

```
Where(r :> r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val = content_control_tag)
```

should be re-written as

```
Where(fun r -> r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val = content_control_tag)
```

using F# lambda syntax.
Also most certainly this will require type annotation on 'r' parameter like:

```
Where(fun (r: put_here_type_of_r) -> ...)
```

Linq extension methods usually look ugly in F# so it is better to use functions from Collection.Seq module: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353635.aspx (Seq is alias for IEnumerable<> in F#)

Also `t.Text = new_text` in F# is not an assignment but equality test. If you want to assign a new value to mutable variable you should use assignment operator: `t.Text <- new_text`

Comment: I disagree that it's usually better to use the `Seq` functions - if the code is using expression trees to compile the query then the `Seq` functions do something very different.

Comment: @kvb Yes, but in the case of simple filtering or mapping F# functions are much readable